# Ubuntu 14.04 OpenStack Installation Failure

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, juju

I've been repeatidly trying to follow this (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack) guide on how to install OpenStack/MASS/juju etc... Unfortunately every single time this has failed. I have been doing it with a dedicated server with a blank Ubuntu 14.04 every time. I get different errors each time. Here are some of them:

```
DEBUG • 11-12 22:33:39 [LINE:50, FUNC:global_exchandler] • cloudinstall.utils • Tra$
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 64, in run
    super().run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/single_install.py", line 139, in do_insta$
    utils.ssh_genkey()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 571, in ssh_genkey
    print("Unable to generate key: {0}".format(out['stderr']))
KeyError: 'stderr'

DEBUG • 11-12 22:32:17 [LINE:50, FUNC:global_exchandler] • cloudinstall.utils • Tra$
  File "/usr/bin/openstack-install", line 104, in <module>
    install.start()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/core.py", line 263, in start
    self.main_loop()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/install.py", line 72, in main_loop
    self.loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 274, in run
    self.screen.run_wrapper(self._run)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 268, in run_wrap$
    return fn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 339, in _run
    self.event_loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 669, in run
    self._loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 690, in _loop
    ready, w, err = select.select(fds, [], fds, timeout)
```

I must clearly be missing something as I have tried to follow this over 15 times now :(.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I've resolved this by not running openstack-instal as root but as my normal user.